# Unconventional Formatting / Parsing XML

Tags: xml

I have the following XML:

```
<XMLResults><ConfMess><RCode>0</RCode><MId>0</MId></ConfMess><COURSE_DATA><THEHEADING>Review Engagements: Inquiry and Analytical Review Procedures and Reporting</THEHEADING><ABSTRACT><!--this file has been generated by v.3.2.1 8/9/2012 8:50:14 AM by JHancock (and called from 'A G&Q Database')--><html><head><title>Course Abstract</title><link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.thelearningcenter.org/cserver/case1/css/theabstract.css' type='text/css'></head><body><div style='text-align: center;' class=h2banner>Course Abstract</div><div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer"><table class="abstract"><tbody class="scrollContent"><tr class="abstract"><td class="abstractCaptions">Main Title</td><td class="abstract" id=courseAbstractTitle>Initial Review: Find Out About Additional Reporting Procedures</td></tr><tr class="abstract"><td class="abstractCaptions">Writer(s)</td><td class="abstract" id=authorsAbstract>Karl Booker<br>Harriet Johnson</td></tr><tr class="abstract"><td class="abstractCaptions">Current Field(s) of Study<sup>1</sup></td><td class="abstract" id=fosAbstract>4.0 study hours in 'History'</td></tr><tr class="abstract"><td class="abstractCaptions">Area Of Study</td><td class="abstract" id=courseLevelAbstract>Medium</td></tr><tr class="abstract"><td class="abstractCaptions">Value (30 min.sec.)<sup>1</sup></td><td class="abstract" id=creditHoursAbstract>3.5</td></tr><tr class="abstract"><td class="abstractCaptions">Must Haves</td><td class="abstract" id=prerequisitesAbstract>None</td></tr><tr class="abstract"><td class="abstractCaptions">Description</td><td class="abstract" id=descriptionAbstract>This topic revolves around discussing important topics in the history field and how they relate to our current situation.</td></tr><tr class="abstract"><td class="abstractCaptions">TheObjective</td><td class="abstract" id=objectivesAbstract><ul><li>Learn more about history and how our modern times have been shaped by it.<li>Plan for the future<li>Help mankind to learn from the past<li>Provide valuable input to others<li>Be greatful for what we have<li>Gain credit for all the hard work we put in<li>Pass this course and move on with our lives.<li>Get a good job and raise a family.<li>Get a vacation home and relax on the beach<li>Soak up the sun and get a tan</ul></td></tr><tr class="abstract" id=idExpirationRow><td class="abstractCaptions">Expires</td><td class="abstract" id=expirationAbstract>This topic is reviewed monthly for value and modified where needed.</td></tr><tr class="abstract"><td class="abstractCaptions">Item ID</td><td class="abstract" id=courseIDabstract>odt</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div id=footnote1ID class="sylFNote"><sup>1</sup>Consult your instructor for infornation on this particular topic</div><div id="idCopyright" class="copyright">© 2004 THIS SCHOOL BOARD</div></body></html></ABSTRACT></COURSE_DATA><STUDY_AREA><SUBJECT>AuditField</SUBJECT><NUMBER_HOURS>3.0</NUMBER_HOURS></FIELD_OF_STUDY></XMLResults>
```

I cannot seem to find a routine that will parse out the "stuff" in the `<ABSTRACT>stuff</ABSTRACT>` section of the XML.  I think it might be due to special characters or something like that.  Can someone help me out with a routine that will work on this and not fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because `<!-- -->` is a comment in XML.  It isn't failing, per se.

```
Comments in XML

The syntax for writing comments in XML is similar to that of HTML.

<!-- This is a comment -->
```

Here is a [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) link.

How you get around that is going to be dependent on the library you are using.  Some libraries may support getting a raw text of that element.  They may also return a comment element.

I would probably just grep the plain text for `<ABSTRACT>(.*)</ABSTRACT>`.  There might be problems with that if you have more than one record per document, so you would need to probably isolate it to each document first.

Comment: Hmmm...  So how would I get around that?

Answer (score 2):

This is not XML. It's a bunch of text with angle brackets.

Not only do you have problems within the `<ABSTRACT>` element, you also have `<STUDY_AREA></FIELD_OF_STUDY>`.

How do you work around it? You don't. You get whoever sent you this trash to send you valid XML. It's not like there aren't a lot of XML editors out there. They should use such a tool to create and/or validate their "XML".